# Add a dynamic div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to add multiple input boxes to enter the data. Initially there will be only one input box and there is an "Add" button next to each generated input boxes to generate multiple text boxes.

If you look at my fiddle there are 3 levels of text boxes in 1st level it has option to enter only 1 level of data but when it comes to level 2, there should be an option to create second level of same parent block so that we can enter the sub data of the main heading. For example If I write State name then I should be able to enter sub categories..

Here is the code for the 1st level menu

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(":radio").click(function(){
         $(".test").hide();
         var show = $(this).attr("data-show");
         $("#"+show).show(300)
     });
        $('.sort').hide();
        $filtr = $('.filtr');

        $filtr.on('click', '.add', function(){
            $(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('.test') );

            $('.sort').show();
        });

        $filtr.on('click', '.del', function(){
           $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        });

        $('#1lev, #2lev, #3lev').hide();

     //For sort up/down
     function moveUp(item) {
    var prev = item.prev();
    if (prev.length == 0)
        return;
    prev.css('z-index', 999).css('position','relative').animate({ top: item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + prev.height() }, 300, function () {
        prev.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertBefore(prev);
    });
}
function moveDown(item) {
    var next = item.next();
    if (next.length == 0)
        return;
    next.css('z-index', 999).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + item.height() }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: next.height() }, 300, function () {
        next.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertAfter(next);
    });
}

$(".filtr").sortable({ items: ".loop", distance: 10 });
$(document).on("click", "button.sort", function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var val = btn.val();
    if (val == 'up')
        moveUp(btn.parents('.loop'));
    else
        moveDown(btn.parents('.loop'));
});

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/9/)**

Required result

[image]

How to clone the `class="filtr" div` as second level panel which works exactly the same as 1st level panel?

Expected code structure should be like this

```
    <div class="filtr"> 
         <!-- we'll clone this one... -->  
         <div class="test" id="2lev"> 
        <div class="loop"> 
            <button value='up' class="sort">Up</button>
            <button value='down' class="sort">Down</button>
            <input type="text" />
            <button class="btn del">x</button>
            <button class="btn add">Add</button> <button class="btn level">></button>

<!--Need to add this div here-->
            <div class="filtr"> 
         <!-- we'll clone this one... -->   
         <div class="test">
        <div class="loop"> 
            <button value='up' class="sort">Up</button>
            <button value='down' class="sort">Down</button>
            <input type="text" />
            <button class="btn del">x</button>
            <button class="btn add">Add</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- here ...-->
    </div>
<!--Need to add this div here-->

        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- here ...-->
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont understand problem. Create template then append it somwhere and put onclick?

Comment: If you look at fiddle, click on level 2 radio button and u can see add button next to input box. Clicking on add button adds up new input box, in the same way I need to show new set of filtr div when I click on > button, this represents the second level of the text box

Comment: Btw, your code need some rework, bcs after clicking from lvl 2 to 1, your lvl 2 templates become lvl 1, here how i would done this, create template for each level like <div id='js-template-lvl1' style='display:none;'>--your template content here -- </div> then add in your form container like <div id='template-container'></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is
[jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/28](http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/28)

```
code
```

But i dont think clone is best solution for this, at least clone template not active element.But this code still need alot of work.

Comment: yes i added         <div class='test' style='padding:10px;'>
        </div> to lvl 2 template and another class hidable at first test

Comment: ok it seems good. Can we do that > button like toggle coz now it adds even on second click

Comment: check if test content is not empty, then dont add anything.

Comment: And one last help. Why the last row's second level has Add button for all the inputs? And How to avoid cloning the sub level when adding a new row by using Add button?

Comment: well you cant avoid that, bcs you clone entire element, thats why i said cloning templates is beter, you can clone it to variable, empty 2 level test container and then append, as for add buttons im gonna look into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the parentsUntil API to get the filtr div

http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/17/

```
 $filtr.on('click', '.level', function(){
          var c = $('<div class="filtr insideFiltr" style="padding-left:10px">'+ 
             '<div class="test" id="4lev">' +  
             '<div class="loop">'+
                '<button value="up" class="sort">Up</button>'+
                '<button value="down" class="sort">Down</button>'+
                '<input type="text" />'+
                '<button class="btn del">x</button>'+
                    '<button class="btn add">Add</button>'+
            '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>');

            c.insertAfter($(this));


      });
```